# NLTK sentiment vader: polarity_scores(text) not working

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to use `polarity_scores()` from the Vader sentiment analysis in NLTK, but it gives me error:

> polarity_scores() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

I am totally a beginner in Python. Appreciate your help!

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer as sid
sentences=["hello","why is it not working?!"]
for sentence in sentences:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
```

Answer (score 11):

`SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` is a class. You need to initialize an object of `SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` and call the `polarity_scores()` method on that.

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer as SIA
sentences=["hello","why is it not working?!"]
sid = SIA()
for sentence in sentences:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
```

You may have to download the lexicon file if you haven't already

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader> d vader_lexicon
Downloader> q
```

Comment: Thank tons! I just figured I was missing the lexicon file. It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first initialize an object of SentimentIntensityAnalyzer then call the method polarity_scores on that.

Try this code:

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

sentences=["hello","why is it not working?!"]
for sentence in sentences:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence) 
print (ss)
```

Comment: Although this maybe a right answer, there is a lack of explanation, please consider add it to your answer.